# Problems to deserialize JSON data to IDbSet<T>

Tags: c#, reflection, fastjson

I have the following json data:

```
{
    "Persons": [
        { "Person": { "FirstName":"A", "Surname": "B" } },
        { "Person": { "FirstName":"C", "Surname": "D" } },
        { "Person": { "FirstName":"E", "Surname": "F" } }
    ]
}
```

My class definitions are:

```
public class PersonContext
{
    public IDbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

When I use fastJSON to deserialize it to an object, I receive a `NullReferenceException`.

```
PersonContext context = fastJSON.JSON.ToObject<PersonContext>(jsonText);
```

Debugging [source code](https://fastjson.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#fastJSON/JSON.cs) of fastJSON, the exception is thrown on `CreateGenericList`, because the `col` variable of the method after calling `(IList)Reflection.Instance.FastCreateInstance(pt);` is null. So after, when it tries to add the parsed dictionary, it raises the exception.

Can I configure serialization process to ensure that `IDbSet<T>` objects are correctly processed?

Thanks in advance.

PS: You can also clone my repo in [github](https://github.com/huorswords/fastJson.Issue) in order to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Can you try deserializing it into an IEnumerable of Person instead?

Comment: @Glitch100 it also fails...

Comment: into a var? Not the PersonContext variable? 

If so that is strange.

Comment: I think that I am not understanding you... Sorry... Do you mean `var context = fastJSON.JSON.ToObject<IEnumerable<Person>>()`? Or just substitute `IDbSet<Person>` by `IEnumerable<Person>`?

Comment: Using the same json file, when I execute `var context = fastJSON.JSON.ToObject<IEnumerable<Person>>(text);` it throws ArgumentNullException (Parameter Name: key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer for my question by mr. Mehdi Gholam (fastJSON owner) on this [thread](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON?msg=5075680#xx5075680xx):

> fastJSON needs concrete types and not interfaces to be defined so it knows what type to create.
>
> So change your code to :
>
> ```
> public class PersonContext
> {
>    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
> }
> ```